# Ember: nested components events bubbling

Tags: javascript, events, ember.js, components, event-bubbling

I've created a set of nested components.

The code is here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hasehija/2/edit.

HTML:

```
{{#level-1}}
    {{#level-2}}
      {{#level-3}}
        <button {{action 'handleAction'}}>
          Click me (yielded)
        </button>
      {{/level-3}}
    {{/level-2}}
 {{/level-1}}
```

JS:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    handleAction: function() {
      alert('Handled in ApplicationController');
    }
  }
});

App.Level1Component = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    handleAction: function() {
      alert('Handled in Level 1');
    }
  }
});

App.Level2Component = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    handleAction: function() {
      alert('Handled in Level 2');
    }
  }
});

App.Level3Component = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    handleAction: function() {
      alert('Handled in Level 3');
      this.set('action', 'handleAction');
      this.sendAction();
    }
  }
});
```

What I want to achieve is to bubble the events in the following way:

`Level3Component -> Level2Component -> Level1Component -> ApplicationController`

Unfortunately, I cannot handle the events inside any of the components; the event bubbled up to `ApplicationController`.

Is there a way to force Components' actions to bubble over the whole hierarchy of components, so that I have the alert shown 4 times (after adding this.sendAction of course)?

Once again, here's a code that you can play with: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hasehija/2/edit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on your example, you must define the component `targetObject` property as:

```
App.Level3Component = Ember.Component.extend({
  action: 'handleAction',
  targetObject: Em.computed.alias('parentView'),  
  actions: {
    handleAction: function() {
      alert('Handled in Level 3');
      this.sendAction();
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hasehija/5/edit

Comment: Thank you! It answers my question entirely! I'm wondering if the thing with the most inner button is really a bug.

Comment: Hmm, probably it's not a bug... The "Click me (inside of component)" button calls `Level3Component`, not `Level2Component` so exactly in the place where it was defined. I think it's a proper behavior.

Comment: I was talking about "Click me (yielded)", it should target the component instead of the ApplicationController

Comment: I was wrong, this is the default behaviour. There is a test which describes this case "Inside a yield, the target points at the original target"   https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/tests/helpers/action_test.js#L117

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, [this question is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005045/how-to-send-an-action-from-a-ember-component-to-a-view-that-wraps-it) and the answer shows how you can do it from the template--you may be able to do:

```
{{#level-1}}
    {{#level-2 targetObject=view}}
      {{#level-3 targetObject=view}}
        <button {{action 'handleAction'}}>
          Click me (yielded)
        </button>
      {{/level-3}}
    {{/level-2}}
 {{/level-1}}
```

Handy if you don't control the inner components or don't want to modify them directly as the other answer does.

I think the reason you say `view` here instead of `parentView` in the above answer is due to Handlebars treating `view` as a special keyword...in any case, using `parentView` in the template didn't work (which puzzles me, but whatever).