# EmberJS: Nested Component in Sliding Bar does not Fire Event

Tags: ember.js

I have the following app:

A sliding bar consists of a top and a bottom layer. On the bottom layer is a button component.
When I slide the top layer away and try to click the button, just the sliding component click fires, **not** the button.

What could be the problem?

**Templates:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h2>Sliding Bar Test</h2>
  
  {{#sliding-bar}}
    {{button-click}}
  {{/sliding-bar}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/sliding-bar">
  <div class="bar top">
    This is on Top
  </div>
  <div class="bar bottom">
    {{yield}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/button-click">
    Click Me
</script>
```

**Ember Code**

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.SlidingBarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  click: function () {
    alert('slider clicked');
  },

  didInsertElement: function() {
    var topElem = this.$('.top');
    TweenMax.to(topElem, 0.25, {css:{left:-148}, overwrite:"all"});
  }
})

App.ButtonClickComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  classNames: ['button'],

  click: function () {
    alert('button clicked');
  }
})
```

**Full Source**

There is also a [JSBin for the full code](http://jsbin.com/mobake/5/edit)

#### Edit:

I changed the lis to divs, but the problem remains. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your Ember code which works just fine but only in the CSS z-index values, which you set. An element with a negative z-index doesn't receive any click events. Just compare to http://jsbin.com/haxovaxe/1/.

Comment: you are right! seems the css I am working with is pretty messed up as well. Need to do some cleanups and feel very confident that it will work then. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There's already a stack overflow question which answers 'nested components events bubbling'. Here it is [Ember: nested components events bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057289/ember-nested-components-events-bubbling)

Accepted answer have bin with solution. In short you need to bind bubbling chain using targetObject. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The answer you were suggesting is about event bubbeling from the button up. I do not even get the event from the button. The slider component catches the event and does not delegate it down to the button. I get the click of the slider but not of the button...