# ember.js | How to bind an event of a sub-component to an action of an outer component

Tags: ember.js

unfortunately i am not able to figure out, how to receive an event of a component i use from within a component.

What i mean actually sounds harder than it is, consider the following toy example, with a component my-outer and another component my-inner (a short explanation follows the code, at the end i link to jsbin).

The templates:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' id='components/my-outer'>
  <div {{bind-attr class="isRed:red"}}>Buttons should toggle my background color</div>
  <button {{action "toggleRed"}}>It works from my-outer</button>
  {{my-inner action="toggleRed"}}
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' id='components/my-inner'>
  <button {{action "action"}}>It doesn't work from my-inner</button>
</script>
```

The javascript:

```
App.MyOuterComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  isRed: false,
  actions: {
    toggleRed: function() {
       this.toggleProperty("isRed");
    }
  }
});
```

my-outer contains a short text, with a background-color, which can be toggled from and to red by invoking the toggleRed action. the first button demonstrates that this works in principle.

now i would like to bind the default action of the second component to this same toggleRed action, that's the point of the following line.

```
{{my-inner action="toggleRed"}}
```

But on clicking the second button (which is part of my-inner) an error is thrown and the action is not fired.

How do I fix this example?

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cabasuru/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Thanks so much in advance
(and this is my first question on so, i am happy about any meta-critics)

Comment: You need to experiment with `target`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember: nested components events bubbling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057289/ember-nested-components-events-bubbling)

Comment: @torazaburo, i don't think, it is a duplicate. the linked one is about events sent from yield, these are usually targeted to the outer controller (in which the element, was created). This one here is about explicit component event binding. (At least that's my take at it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question actually missed the main point. What goes wrong in the example above, is that the action helper in the inner component

```
<button {{action "action"}}>It doesn't work from my-inner</button>
```

does not trigger the default action associated with the component. Instead it invokes a new event named `action`, which is not allowed to bubble (due to the component confinement).

It turns out, there are two ways to solve that:

1. Properly reroute the event in an actions block on the `my-inner` component

   ```
   <button {{action "my-action"}}>...</button>
   ```

   together with a definition of the `my-action` action for `my-inner`:

   ```
   App.MyInnerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
     actions: {
       myaction: function(){
         this.sendAction();
       }
     }
   });
   ```

   This is basically, the idea @CodeJack proposes, with the difference,
   that here we rely on the wiring, which is set-up in the template of `my-outer`.
   http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cabasuru/3/edit
2. As @torazaburo hinted at, setting the target property on the `my-inner` component to the `my-outer` component allows the event triggered from the action helper to bypass the component isolation.

   `{{my-inner target=controller}}` in the `my-outer` template and a `<button {{action "toggleRed"}}>...</button>` in the `my-inner` template.

Answer (score 2):

Since Components work just like views, easiest way is to get the `parentView` and forward the action. You may have to handle the action in `my-inner` like following.

```
App.MyInnerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  isRed: false,
  actions: {
    toggleRed: function() {
      this.get('parentView').send('toggleRed');
    }
  }

});
```

You can see outer component can be accessed as `parentView` in inner component. Here is the working jsbin link
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cabasuru/5/edit